Реализация чата в Aiogram через бота
Не работает пересылка сообщений между пользователями через бот, я новичок в питоне, помогите пожалуйста решить задачу.
import asyncio
import logging
import os
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, types, F
from aiogram.filters import Command, StateFilter
from aiogram.types import InlineKeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup
from aiogram.fsm.state import State, StatesGroup
from aiogram.fsm.context import FSMContext
from aiogram.fsm.storage.memory import MemoryStorage
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()
API_TOKEN = os.getenv('API_TOKEN')  # Токен вашего бота
CHANNEL_ID = os.getenv('CHANNEL_ID')  # ID вашего канала (может быть отрицательным для приватного канала)

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

bot = Bot(token=API_TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(storage=MemoryStorage())

class ChatStates(StatesGroup):
    in_chat = State()  # Состояние активного чата

# Словарь для хранения активных чатов
active_chats = {}

@dp.message(Command("start"))
async def start(message: types.Message):
    logging.debug("Команда /start получена.")
    keyboard = InlineKeyboardMarkup(inline_keyboard=[
        [InlineKeyboardButton(text="Да", callback_data="yes"), InlineKeyboardButton(text="Нет", callback_data="no")]
    ])
    await message.answer("Хочешь пообщаться?", reply_markup=keyboard)

# Обработка ответа "Да"
@dp.callback_query(F.data == "yes")
async def process_callback(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery):
    user_id = callback_query.from_user.id
    logging.debug(f"Пользователь {user_id} нажал 'Да'")

    chat_button = InlineKeyboardMarkup(inline_keyboard=[
        [InlineKeyboardButton(text="Начать чат", callback_data=f"start_chat:{user_id}")]
    ])

    # Отправка сообщения в канал с кнопкой для начала чата
    await bot.send_message(CHANNEL_ID, "Знакомство в слепую. Нажмите, чтобы начать чат!", reply_markup=chat_button)
    await callback_query.message.answer("Сообщение отправлено в канал. Ждем ответа от собеседника.")
    await callback_query.answer()

# Обработка ответа "Нет"
@dp.callback_query(F.data == "no")
async def process_no(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery):
    await callback_query.message.answer("Пока приходи еще!")

# Начало чата
@dp.callback_query(lambda c: c.data.startswith("start_chat"))
async def start_chat(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery, state: FSMContext):
    user1_id = int(callback_query.data.split(":")[1])  # ID первого пользователя
    user2_id = callback_query.from_user.id  # ID второго пользователя

    if user1_id == user2_id:
        await callback_query.message.answer("Вы не можете начать чат с самим собой.")
        return

    # Устанавливаем активный чат
    active_chats[user1_id] = user2_id
    active_chats[user2_id] = user1_id

    logging.debug(f"Чат начался между пользователями {user1_id} и {user2_id}")

    # Устанавливаем состояние чата для обоих пользователей
    await state.set_state(ChatStates.in_chat)
    await state.update_data(partner_id=user2_id)

    # Уведомляем пользователей о начале чата
    await bot.send_message(user1_id, "Чат начался. Вы можете отправлять сообщения собеседнику.")
    await bot.send_message(user2_id, "Чат начался. Вы можете отправлять сообщения собеседнику.")

    # Логируем успешный переход в состояние
    logging.debug(f"Пользователь {user1_id} и {user2_id} находятся в состоянии чата.")

@dp.message(StateFilter(ChatStates.in_chat))
async def chat_message_handler(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    sender_id = message.from_user.id
    logging.debug(f"Получено сообщение от {sender_id}: {message.text}")

    # Получаем ID собеседника
    data = await state.get_data()
    recipient_id = data.get('partner_id')

    if recipient_id and recipient_id in active_chats:  # Проверяем, что у собеседника активный чат
        logging.debug(f"Отправка сообщения пользователю {recipient_id}")
        await bot.send_message(recipient_id, f"Сообщение от собеседника: {message.text}")
    else:
        logging.warning(f"Пользователь {sender_id} попытался отправить сообщение, но чата нет.")
        await message.answer("Ваш чат завершен или собеседник отключился.")
        logging.debug(f"Получено сообщение от {sender_id} вне активного чата.")

# Для обработки всех других сообщений
@dp.message()
async def handle_unhandled_messages(message: types.Message):
    logging.warning(f"Необработанное сообщение от {message.from_user.id}: {message.text}")
    await message.answer("Ваше сообщение не было обработано, возможно, вы не находитесь в активном чате.")

# Завершение чата
@dp.message(Command("end_chat"), StateFilter(ChatStates.in_chat))
async def end_chat(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    user_id = message.from_user.id
    partner_id = active_chats.get(user_id)

    if partner_id:
        await bot.send_message(partner_id, "Ваш собеседник завершил чат.")
        await bot.send_message(user_id, "Вы завершили чат.")

        # Удаляем участников из активных чатов и очищаем состояние
        del active_chats[user_id]
        del active_chats[partner_id]

        await state.clear()
        await dp.fsm.storage.get_context(bot=bot, user=partner_id).clear()

        logging.debug(f"Чат завершен между {user_id} и {partner_id}.")
    else:
        await message.answer("У вас нет активного чата для завершения.")
        logging.warning(f"Пользователь {user_id} попытался завершить несуществующий чат.")

async def main():
    await bot.delete_webhook(drop_pending_updates=True)
    await dp.start_polling(bot)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        logging.debug("Запуск бота...")
        asyncio.run(main())
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"Произошла ошибка: {e}")


Вопрос решен, через отказ от FSM, если есть идеи как это сделать с FSM буду признателен!
